# Python dict comprehension error while extracting data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Dict comprehensions with conditions

I have a Pandas dataframe from where I want to extract data to a dictionary.
'addresses' is a dict where keys are the level 0 indices of the dataframe (but not all of them). I want to do such operation:

```
dfl = df1.loc[df1.tagkey.isin(['building:levels'])]
levels = {k : dfl.at[k, 'tagvalue'] for k in addresses.keys() if k in dfl.index else 0}
```

But I receive an error of invalid syntax. Don't understand why

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input, what is the output of `df.head().to_dict('tight')`? Also provide the explicit expected output.

Comment: A syntax error shouldn't be dependent on what's in the dataframe.  Please post the exact error message. It will have a `^` that points to the place of the error. Usually these are due to misplaced brackets.

Comment: Input In [21]
    levels = {k : dfl.at[k, 'tagvalue'] for k in addresses.keys() if k in dfl.index else 0}
It points to else word

Comment: And what is addresses?

Comment: Your ternary is in the wrong place. It should be `levels = {k : dfl.at[k, 'tagvalue'] if k in dfl.index else 0 for k in addresses.keys()}`, if you want the value to be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a ternary in the right part of the comprehension:

```
{… for … in … if … else …}
```

You can only do it in the left part:

```
{… if … else … for … in …}
```

In your case this should be:

```
levels = {k : dfl.at[k, 'tagvalue'] if k in dfl.index else 0
          for k in addresses.keys()}
```